# Why isn't there 1' to 2' direction or something else except 5' to 3' in dna replication?

Tags: dna

I hope i would get logical answers. I  request to post it as soon as possible.

Comment: Welcome to Biology Stack Exchange. I would highly recommend to read the tour before asking any questions. You will also earn your first badge. Take the tour here: https://biology.stackexchange.com/tour . Your question is a replication of the following question: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/15082/what-does-5-and-3-mean-in-dna-and-rna-strands .. Please check the link provided for answers.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

<sup>[[Source](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiypcvtmfXUAhVHNY8KHWm6CoMQjRwIBw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bio.miami.edu%2Fdana%2F250%2F250F12_7.html&psig=AFQjCNHSzjJoHY0Mi8DoXgBO5kO8UOf5Rw&ust=1499449238689707)]</sup>

DNA is a polynucleotide. The above structure is of a nucleotide which has three components, a nitrogenous base(yellow), a pentose sugar(purple) and a phosphate group. These nucleotides form phosphodiester linkages to form a polynucleotide.

[image]

<sup>[[Source](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/XoXCih7xYEn1NZ6adTkAfqYIB3G-Pc5xN4FgpH5w-zKVErHJ3DXVux_XDRTUpFBApraF=s120)]</sup>

These phosphodiester linkages are formed between 3' and 5' carbons of the pentose sugar which is shown in the above image.

[image]

<sup>[[Source](https://www.google.co.in/search?safe=strict&q=5+to+3+dna&tbm=isch&tbs=simg:CAQSlQEJGfcPVsgHA6MaiQELEKjU2AQaAggKDAsQsIynCBpiCmAIAxIotxOqE7UTrBOrE74TqRO7E4sIzh2cPY83nT3wP7w-xj3CPsE-nz3WPxowizg6jIxJf1BpB0HeXcbsGj7CcLPZtiS1-qgFt-cc_1SeN_1jAowwrhyK72Ee1LgpnjIAQMCxCOrv4IGgoKCAgBEgRblyMDDA&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjypoT5mvXUAhULOo8KHVVsCl4Qwg4IJCgA)]</sup>

The end of DNA having a free phosphate group at 5' of pentose sugar is known as the 5'-end of DNA, and the end of DNA having a free hydroxyl group at 3' of pentose sugar is called the 3'-end of DNA.

[Here](https://www.mvls.gla.ac.uk/Teaching/SLS-FTB/dna.html), you can play with the DNA.